# !start not being found on vim command line

Tags: windows, shell, vim

Windows command line has this command `start` that executes the argument with the default program. This is not an executable so I cannot just set it to path. If so, is there a way for me to run it from gvim command line? `!start` returns:

```
C:/cygwin/bin/bash -c "start"
/usr/bin/bash: start: command not found
shell returned 127
Hit any key to close this window...
```

and if I include any arguments, I get

```
E371: Command Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal `cmd.exe` commands can be executed with:

```
cmd /c whatever
```

(where `whatever` is the command)

However, given that's a pain to type in, I'd consider creating a `go.cmd` (for example) batch file to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already running cygwin, use [`cygstart`](http://alumni.soe.ucsc.edu/~you/notes/cygwin-install.html#mozTocId125492)

Comment: I found it working in gvim, contrary to what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:! start` (with a space between `:!` and `start`) fixed the `E371: Command Not Found` bug for me with gVim under Windows 7 without cygwin.

That served me as a workaround for vim's "special treatment" of `:!start` (without the space) which seems to be buggy.

See [`:help :!start`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#insert-index).

Answer (score 0):

To access Cygwin commands inside Vim, for example,

```
%!grep abc
```

two things are needed:

1. Your Windows PATH variable needs to include the Windows version of the full path of the directory containing the Cygwin command executables, typically, `C:\cygwin64\bin`
2. Add set `shell=C:/cygwin64/bin/bash` to your `_vimrc`